# I am to build a "dynamic trivia game using jQuery"

Tags: javascript, jquery, animated-gif

How to append a gif so that i don't get redirected thru UR from using "" nation from google?

how to set a decremental timer (30 sec) to lap upon an on click event of specific buttons to still allow my trivia game to work?
(*also to make a gif from above to append too from the onclick event*)

I TRIED OTHER EXAMPLES none of which remotely close what I'm trying to achieve. Maybe because I asked too specific and didn't summarize but given the nature of the problem, you see why I'm having an issue; only 5 weeks into this trying to intake and render as much info as I can, and I've been told I'm on the right track as far as effort but I'm not content with myself yet I'm trying as hard as I can.

//JAVASCRIPT CODE I HAVE SO FAR
//I HAVE THREE BUTTONS SET UP TO GET THE ELEMENTS FOR.

//Timer INSERT HERE
    var count=30;

```
var counter=setInterval(timer, 1000); //1000 will  run it every 1 second

function timer()
{
  count=count-1;
  if (count <= 0)
  {
     clearInterval(counter);
     return;
  }

  document.getElementById("seconds").innerHTML = count + " secconds left!";
}

//Trivia Game -- Final submitBtn
function checkFinRes() {

    var question1 = document.quiz.question1.value;
    var question2 = document.quiz.question2.value;
    var question3 = document.quiz.question3.value;
    var correct = 0;

        if (question1 == "1943") {
            question1 = true;
            correct++;
        } else {
            question1 = false;
        }

        if (question2 == "Bill Gates") {
            question2 = true;
            correct++;  
        } else {
            question2 = false;
        }

    if (question3 == "All of the above!") {
        question3 = true;
        correct++;
    } else {
        question3 = false;
    }


document.getElementById("afterSub").style.visibility = "visible";


document.getElementById("amtCorrect").innerHTML = "You got " + correct + " 
correct!";

}
```

I've run my examples and trying whatever I could do but I know none of those thrown in here will be close to what I get back. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: I'm afraid it's not too clear what you're asking. What do you mean by `how to append a gif so that i dont get redirected thru UR from using "" nation from google?`?

Comment: What I'm going to do is to have a container div holding a: timerDiv, questionDiv,  choicesDiv, && buttonDiv;
/
I want to have the timer  be decremental from a to b, (30,0), respectively, with zero being gameOver();
USER has 60 seconds come rush through 5 quiz trivia questions.
Only way to slow down the timer is to get the (current[q])questionNumber correct(true).to trigger a pause, followed with a gif, appended to the screen. (2 different outcomes of which gif appears: gifTrue!!gifFalse);